# Wait for a twisted service to start before starting another

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.application

I have written a proxy server that uses twisted's application framework. At it's core there it uses a DHT to resolve things. The DHT client takes a few seconds to start, so i want to make sure that the proxy only accepts connections after the DHT is ready.

```
# there is a class like 
class EntangledDHT(object):
    # connects to the dht

# create the client
dht = EntangledDHT.from_config(config)

# when it can be used this deferred fires
# i want to wait for this before creating the "real" application
dht.ready


# the proxy server, it uses the dht client
port = config.getint(section, 'port')

p = CosipProxy(host=config.get(section, 'listen'),
               port=port,
               dht=dht,
               domain=config.get(section, 'domain'))


## for twistd
application = service.Application('cosip')

serv = internet.UDPServer(port, p)
serv.setServiceParent(service.IService(application))
```

How do I turn the `EntangledDHT` into some kind of service that Twisted will wait for before starting the `CosipProxy` service? Is there any mechanism in twisted that does this for me? Or do I have to add a callback to `dht.ready` that creates the rest of the application? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `serv.setServiceParent(service.IService(application))` right away.  Instead, wait to call it in your callback to `dht.ready`.  This will cause it to be started if the application service is already running.

Also, it doesn't look like `dht` itself is an `IService`.  It should be; or rather, the thing that calls `from_config` should be a service, since apparently `from_config` is going to kick off some connections (at least, that's what it looks like, if `dht.ready` is ever going to fire, in this example).  Your plugin or tac file should be *constructing* a service, not *starting* a service.  Nothing should happen until that first `startService` is called.

Comment: Sorry i didn't reply in a while, i didn't have time to work on this. When I turn the `EntangledDHT` to a IService it should only start connecting to the network in `startService`, not when the obhect is created? I guess the library I'm using (entangled) doesn't do this quite right either, since the Protocol class it defines also does `twisted.internet.reactor.listenUDP( .. )`?